# Variable Object Attribute Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I access an object attribute based on a variable in an Angular template?  I have an object that has an attribute based on a user selection, so how do I tell the Angular template to get that value?  For example, the user chooses q26 and I access the object like this:

```
{{ item.q26 }}
```

it woks no problem.  But if a user chooses q28, it obviously wouldn't work.  I can successfully pass the value the user chooses to the template but how do I get Angular to read that variable as an object attribute.  I know this doesn't work but the idea would be:

```
{{ item }}.{{ user_selection }}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `{{ item[user_selection] }}` just like with objects.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your code on JSFiddle or Plunker.